# C file transfer question

Tags: c, sockets

I implemented a client-server program that allows to transfer files b/w them. The server is using select() to check changes of sockets. 
Every test is good except this one:
- When server is sending a huge file to client (not yet finished), client hit "Ctrl-C" to kill the client program, then the server is killed too :(

The snippet:

```
fprintf(stderr,"Reading done, sending ...\n");
if(send(sockClient, sendBuf, chunk_length, 0) < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to send through socket %d \n", sockClient);
    return -1;
}
fprintf(stderr,"Sending done\n");
```

When the client is killed, the server terminal displays:

```
user$./server
Reading done, sending ...
Sending done
Reading done, sending ...
Sending done
Reading done, sending ...
Sending done
Reading done, sending ...
user$
```

What's wrong with it? 
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to ignore SIGPIPE. Try adding something like this in your server startup:

```
#include <signal.h>
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `send()` call may be used only when the socket is in a `connected` state (so that the intended recipient is known). the return is the bytescount sent...
`if(send(sockClient, sendBuf, chunk_length, 0) < 0)`
so when disconnected, it skipped out...

Comment: Right, what you describe as "skipped out" is where your process receives a SIGPIPE from the system.

Comment: You can control whether you get a signal with MSG_NOSIGNAL in place of the 0 in the send().  You still get error EPIPE back (though if you don't have a SIGPIPE handler installed, the send() doesn't return).

Answer (score 0):

MSG_NOSIGNAL is not portable and will not be available on Windows.